# Graphing a solid between two structures using spherical coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I graph the solid that lies above the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=z$?

I tried `SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/4}, {\[Rho], 0, 2}]` which doesn't give me a solid, how do I do this?

Sorry I am a beginner with mathematica

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
RegionPlot3D[z >= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= z, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to use spherical coordinates?

Comment: You could define an `ParametricRegion` for the sphere in spherical coordineates. But the cartesian formulation is much more easy. I think!

Comment: Can you show me the spherical method for it please?

Comment: Try something linke `halfsphere = 
 ParametricRegion[{r {Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], 
      Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Theta]]} + {0, 0, 1/2},
   
    (0 <= r <= 1/2) && (0 <= \[Theta] <= Pi/2) && (-Pi <= \[Phi] <= 
      Pi)  }, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]`  . Should work in MMA v12 (Sorry I couldn't test it in v11)

Answer (score 2):

You asked to do this in spherical coordinates so see if this is good enough for you.

```
r[phi_,theta_]:=Piecewise[{
  {0,Pi/4<phi<Pi/2},
  {10*phi+1-5/2*Pi,Pi/4-1/10<phi<Pi/4},
  {1,0<phi<Pi/4-1/10}}];
SphericalPlot3D[r[phi,theta],{phi,0,Pi/2},{theta,0,2Pi},PlotPoints->100]
```

That `r` is zero outside the range of the cone, increases rapidly to make up the surface of the cone and then is 1 to make up the sphere on top of the cone.

That doesn't give a perfect cone because the tip and junction between the cone and the sphere aren't well rendered in the plot. You can increase the `PlotPoints` to make this better.

EDIT

Better rendering while still using `SphericalPlot3D`

```
Show[SphericalPlot3D[10*phi+1-5/2*Pi,{phi,Pi/4-.1,Pi/4},{theta,0,2Pi},PlotRange->{0,1}],
  SphericalPlot3D[1,{phi,0,Pi/4},{theta,0,2Pi},PlotRange->{0,1}]]
```

You could use this method to graph a variety of surfaces in spherical coordinates.

As a hint, I found the coefficients of `-10*phi+5/2*Pi` by `Solve[{m (Pi/4-1/10)+b == 0, m Pi/4+b == 1},{m,b}]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine two `RevolutionPlot3D`s using `Show`:

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{t, t}, {t, 0, 1/2}], 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{Cos[t] / 2, Sin[t] / 2 + 1/2}, {t, 0, Pi}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]